# Как достать индекс выбранного элемента в QTreeWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyside2, qtreewidget

Как достать индекс выбранного элемента в `treeWidget`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае индекс должен быть "**1**".

Пробовал:

`self.treeWidget.selectedIndexes()[0], self.treeWidget.currentIndex()`

пока не получается

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_item)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.delete)
        self.count = 0

    def add_item(self):

        item = QTreeWidgetItem()
        item.setText(0, "Hello")
        item.setText(1, "world")
        item.setText(2, '2021')
        self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(item)
        self.count += 1

    def delete(self):
        self.treeWidget.removeItemWidget(self.treeWidget.currentItem(), 0)
        self.treeWidget.removeItemWidget(self.treeWidget.currentItem(), 1)
        self.treeWidget.removeItemWidget(self.treeWidget.currentItem(), 2)


    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(Dialog)
        self.treeWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 256, 192))
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 120, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("Dialog", "1"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, _translate("Dialog", "2"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(2, _translate("Dialog", "3"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Добавить"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Удалить"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S. Nick добавил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer.** Создайте другой класс,
**который наследуется от соответствующего виджета**, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

> QTreeWidgetItem *QTreeWidget::**invisibleRootItem**() const
>
> Возвращает невидимый корневой элемент виджета-дерева.
>
> Невидимый корневой элемент обеспечивает доступ к элементам верхнего уровня виджета-дерева
> через QTreeWidgetItem API, что позволяет писать функции,
> которые могут обрабатывать элементы верхнего уровня и их дочерние элементы единообразно;
> например, рекурсивные функции.

> QTreeWidgetItem *QTreeWidgetItem::**takeChild**(int index)
>
> Удаляет список потомков и возвращает его, в противном случае возвращает пустой список.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(Dialog)
        self.treeWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 256, 192))
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 120, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("Dialog", "1"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, _translate("Dialog", "2"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(2, _translate("Dialog", "3"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Добавить"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Удалить"))


#class MainWindow(QMainWindow):                                          # --- QMainWindow
class MainWindow(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):                                    # +++ QDialog
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        headers = ['A','B','C',]                                         # +++
        self.treeWidget.setColumnCount(len(headers))                     # +++
        self.treeWidget.setHeaderLabels(headers)                         # +++   
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_item)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self._delete)
        self.count = 0

    def add_item(self):
        item = QTreeWidgetItem()
        item.setText(0, f"Hello {self.count}")
        item.setText(1, "world")
        item.setText(2, '2021')
        
        # void QTreeWidget::addTopLevelItems(const QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> &items)
        # Добавляет список элементов как элементы верхнего уровня в виджете.
        self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(item)
        self.count += 1

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def _delete(self):
        print(f'\ninvisibleRootItem = {QTreeWidget.invisibleRootItem(self.treeWidget)}')
        print(f'row = {self.treeWidget.currentIndex().row()}')
        
        item = QTreeWidget.invisibleRootItem(self.treeWidget).takeChild(
            self.treeWidget.currentIndex().row())
        print(f'item = {item}') 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]